# How to use Sum() function with condition?

Tags: sql, t-sql, ms-access

I have an Access database. There is a table named cost with bottom value:

```html
  reson          Cost       Type
------------    ------   ------
  A1              2500      1
  A1              6500      1
  A2              95000     2
  A3              2500      1
  A1              6500      1
  A4              50000     2
```

Now I want a query that calculate sum of all cost filed where type = 2 and sum of cost filed where type = 1 and substract the first value from the second value.

For example, the above pic calculate final result:

```html
Sum of Type 2 = 145000
Sum of Type 1 = 18000
-------------------------
Final Result = 127000
```

My Sql Code

```
select iif(type = 2, sum(cost), -sum(cost)) As col1 from cost  group by type
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: @WEI_DBA I edited my question

Comment: @Igor thanks. i edited my question

Comment: @saeed No, you haven't, really. Re-read the comment that Igor posted.

Comment: Better but keep in mind that the `final result` you mention is text so what you are asking for is ambiguous. Change your question to mention the structure of the data you want to return. Example: do you want multiple results or do you want it all in a single result set? If the latter then what is the structure of that result set?

Comment: @Igor thanks, I want just a single result. just final result in a cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change *T1* to the name of your table.

```
SELECT Sum(T.Type1) AS Type1, Sum(T.Type2) AS Type2, Sum(T.Type2) - Sum(T.Type1) AS DIFF
FROM 
(
    SELECT Sum(T1.Cost) AS Type1, 0 AS Type2
    FROM T1
    WHERE (((T1.Type)=1))
    UNION
    SELECT 0 AS Type1, Sum(T1.Cost) AS Type2
    FROM T1
    WHERE (((T1.Type)=2))
)  AS T;
```

---

> Type1    |    Type2    |     DIFF
>
> 18000    |    145000   |    127000

Comment: thanks and i could writh this query : `select Sum(iif(type=2,(cost),-(cost))) from cost`

Answer (score 2):

First off, I'm sorry you have to deal with such obnoxious hostility when asking your question here. You asked your question perfectly fine, laying out your table structure, and your desired result. It's understandable that you are new to queries and need help creating them. Not every answer requires code, and not every person knows where to start.

Here is your answer:

**Step 1**
Make sure you have your table created with the data you provided
[image]

**Step 2**
Create a new query named qySumType1. Build it like this, so it sums everything of type=1. make sure to click the totals button.
[image]

**Step 3**
Create another query, name this one qySumType2. This query should sum everything of type=2.
[image]

**Step 4**
Now create another query called "Final". Add both of your previous queries to it. Now create an expression in the last column to calculate the difference between the 2 numbers. Just like this.
[image]

And there you have it. Now just run the Final query anytime you want to get the difference.
[image]

Hope this helps! I can't tell you how many times I've started learning something new and relied on a community to help me get started. Always just try your best and wait for a decent answer to your question. Good luck!

Comment: Tips thank you very much.